# For loop on API

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop

I have a list of around 28K numbers in  a list named "**y**" and I am running a for loop on API to send Messages but this takes a lot of time (to be exact 1.2797 seconds per call)

Code:

```
import timeit

start = timeit.default_timer()

for i in y:
    data = {'From': 'XXXX', 'To': str(i),
            'Body': "ABC ABC" }
    requests.post('https://xxxx:xx@api.xxx.com/v1/Accounts/xxx/Sms/send',data=data)

stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

How can I reduce the time for this ?

Comment: If the API accepts many you could send them over all at once

Comment: You are timing all the requests, not just one.

Comment: @Guy I timed one single request and got 1.27 seconds, later changed it to post the question

Comment: High-latency requests are precisely what ``async`` code exists for. Have a look at async frameworks such as ``asyncio``, ``trio`` or ``curio``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asyncio or Multithreading are the two possible solutions to optimize your code, and both basically do the same under the hood:

## Threaded

```py
import timeit
import threading
import time

y = list(range(50))


def post_data(server, data, sleep_time=1.5):
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    # request.post(server, data=data)


start = timeit.default_timer()

server = 'https://xxxx:xx@api.xxx.com/v1/Accounts/xxx/Sms/send'

threads = []
for i in y:
    # if you don't need to wait for your threads don't hold them in memory after they are done and instead do
    # threading.Thread(target, args).start()
    # instead. Especially important if you want to send a large number of messages
    threads.append(threading.Thread(target=post_data,
                            args=(server, {'From': 'XXXX', 'To': str(i), 'Body': "ABC ABC"}))
    threads[-1].start()

for thread in threads:
    # optional if you want to wait for completion of the concurrent posts
    thread.join()

stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

## Asyncio

[Referring to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51051980/6301103).

```py
import timeit
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

y =  list(range(50)
_executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(len(y))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def post_data(server, data, sleep_time=1.5):
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    # request.post(server, data=data)

async def post_data_async(server, data):
    return await loop.run_in_executor(_executor, lambda: post_data(server, data))


async def run(y, server):
    return await asyncio.gather(*[post_data_async(server, {'From': 'XXXX', 'To': str(i), 'Body': "ABC ABC"})
                                  for i in y])


start = timeit.default_timer()

server = 'https://xxxx:xx@api.xxx.com/v1/Accounts/xxx/Sms/send'

loop.run_until_complete(run(y, server))

stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

When using an API that does not support asyncio but would profit from concurrency, like your use-case, I'd tend towards using threading as it's easier to read IMHO. If your API/Library does support asyncio, go for it! It's great!

On my machine with a list of 50 elements the asyncio solutions clocks in at 1.515 seconds of runtime while the threaded solution needs about 1.509 seconds, when executing 50 instances of `time.sleep(1.5)`.